# Python ASCII Art

Tags: python

I have a question regarding Python ASCII Art.

```
User inputs 6.
XXXXXX
X    X
XX  XX
XX  XX
X    X
XXXXXX

User inputs 8.
XXXXXXXX
X      X
X      X
XXX  XXX
XXX  XXX
X      X
X      X
XXXXXXXX
```

How would I craft something like this in Python 3, using input from the user?

Could someone point me in the right direction. I just started learning python at home. This is one of the questions in the bonus quiz section of a book I purchased from Amazon.

Answer (score 1):

Create a simple algorithm that would generate those characters, by using the math patterns that would be necessary to create those characters. For that example, notice you can use a pattern for the digits you gave.

For example (say the user input is `i`):

The first line `XXXXXX` is six characters. The example with an input of `i=8` is eight characters. So why not output the the character `X` for `i` times?

`print "X"*i`

That's your first line. Now continue with the rest of the lines.

The second line is `X    X`. There are four spaces for an input of `i=6`, six spaces for an input of `i=8`. So there's a pattern there, clearly. So why output an `X`, then `i-2` spaces, then another `X`?

`print "X" + " "*(i-2) + "X"`

Complete the third line the same way:

`print "X"*(i-2)/2 + " "*(i/2-2) + "X"*(i/2)/2`

You should be able to complete the rest from here, to reverse the character and try out various inputs. Think about what happens for other integer values that aren't `i=6`, `8`, `10`, `12`, etc. You can use `round`, `floor`, or a variation on these patterns in order to handle inputs such as `i=7` and `9`.